# How to use Pushid with Uid Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add data to Firebase in this structure from android application:

```
UserID: { 
  uniqueId: {
     Data1: ""
     Data1: ""
   }
  uniqueId: {
     Data2: ""
     Data2: ""
   }
}
```

But I am struggling to get the UserID working with the uniqueID, can someone please help;

```
DatabaseReference mypostref = databaseReference.push();
        databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(Personname: "Data", personaddress: "Data");
```

I have managed to (I think) get hold of the unique id through creating this: mypostref but how do I join the two together? Own its on the below code works fine but its only with the Uid. I want to break it further down so it has unique ID for each data set.

```
 databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(Friend1Name: "Data", Friend1Address: "Data");
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "join the two together" ? do you want to combine the push key string from `push()` method with the string from `user.getUid()` as one string key for the object? why not just save it with user's uid as the key for the object instead of combining the uid with the push key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference parentUserNode = databaseReference.child(user.getUid);
//Edit: Added way of saving the key generated by push
String keyFromPush = parentUserNode.push().getKey();
parentUserNode.child(keyFromPush).setValue(/*Add whatever value you want in here*/).
```

This will create a node like this:

```
uid: { 
  uniqueid01: {
    ...
  }
  uniqueid02: {
   ...
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted :) quick question, is there a way to keep a record of the pushId within android or store the ID in a variable for later use?

Comment: Btw, need to wait 18 minutes to accept answer and sadly I need 15 rep to vote up.

Comment: it says incompatible type on this line: String keyFromPush = parentUserNode.push();

Comment: Sorry I must have copied before your answer was updated